# ASP.NET Core Model Validation Errors displaying in wrong order

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

**Issue:**
The Model errors are not displayed according to the model definition, they are displayed randomly.

This is happening in ASP.NET core app. I never had this issue in regular asp.net mvc application.

Is there any setting i have to enable in asp.net core razor pages? Or am i doing some thing wrong completely. Please help.

**UI Display**
Errors are displayed in random format:

- DOB is required
- Last Name is required
- Child EI ID is required
- First Name is required
- School District is required
- Date Of Referral is required

**ViewModel Defintion:**

```
public class DocumentViewModel 
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "First Name is required")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z- ']+$", ErrorMessage = "First Name should not contain any special character or number.")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Last Name is required")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z- ']+$", ErrorMessage = "Last Name should not contain any special character or number.")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Child EI ID is required")]
    public int? ChildEIID { get; set; }

   [Required(ErrorMessage = "DOB is required")]
   [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime? DOB { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "District is required")]
    public string District { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Date Of Referral is required")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime? DateOfReferral{ get; set; }
```

}

**POST METHOD**

```
 [HttpPost]
 [AutoValidateAntiforgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Documents(UploadDocumentViewModel viewModel)
    {


        //string errorMessages = "";
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return ModelErrors();
        }

        return Json(new { status = "success", message = "Documents Uploaded." });
    }
```

**MODEL ERRORS RETURN METHOD**

```
private ActionResult ModelErrors()
    {
        var modelStateErrors = this.ModelState.Keys.SelectMany(key => this.ModelState[key].Errors);
        var message = "<ul>";

        foreach (var modelStateError in modelStateErrors)
        {
            message += "<li>" + modelStateError.ErrorMessage + "</li>";
        }
        message += "</ul>";
        return Json(new { status = "error", message = message });
    }
```

Comment: Did you figure this out? I am having the same issue in a .NET Core 5 project and it's never been a problem before.

Comment: We didn't have this issue in earlier version of .net core, but are experiencing it in .net 7.  Interestingly, the helper method @Html.ValidationSummary(false) does observe model field order but I haven't found a way to take advantage of that as yet.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the error messages to be sorted, you should define a sort criteria. Apparently you've found a situation where no deterministic order is present.

If you want to sort the errors by property name, this should the trick:

```
var modelStateErrors = this.ModelState.Keys.OrderBy(x => x).SelectMany(key => this.ModelState[key].Errors);
```

If you want the keys to sorted by another criteria, you could create an attribute to decorate the properties and use reflection to sort the error messages in that order.

However, in 2020 it's pretty uncommon to have this sort of list of error messages below an input form. Instead, you should display each specific error message next (or below) the invalid input form field. Additionally, you can show all ModelState errors without a key (as they can't be located next to an input field) in an ul/li summary. This may be the case if you have validation errors that do not directly belong to a specific input field.